# C# Selenium can't find element with WebDriverWait, i can see and click on it manually

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium

Element im trying to locate:
[image: See the element here]

```
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//use[@xlink:href='#core_mail']")));

        File.WriteAllText("html.txt", browser.PageSource);
```

that just times out.. and the page loads way before 60 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svg` has a *default namespace*. You have to account for it:

```
//svg:use[@xlink:href='#core_mail']
```

Or ignore it with [`local-name()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/local-name):

```
//*[local-name() = 'use' and @xlink:href='#core_mail']
```

Though, to be fair, you don't have to dive into the markup that deeply, your "email" button is much higher in the tree - see the very first parent element partially visible on the screenshot - that's your desired element you probably want to locate instead.

Comment: Thank you. You were correct, though i tried with "//pos-icon-item[@icon='core_mail']" to make it work. So yeah your suggestion about not going so deep is actually valid. I will mark as answer in 2 minutes since it doenst let me do it before that

Comment: By the way, something strange that i dont know if its related to this, but when i save the PageSource property of the driver object to a file, i get the impression i don't see the full page source there, by that i mean after javascript has done its magic. For example in my image you can see that i have a message saying "mail.com Update" and i cant see that on the source

Comment: @JoaoVitor glad to help! two general things could've happened: there is some js executed after you've got the page source. Or, that part is in the iframe - the page source would not recursively get the iframe page sources.

Comment: Totally true, the whole inbox is inside an iframe, in this case i think i could use driver.SwitchTo() to work with them. Thanks again!